# Let's say I don't need to have a burger-sidebar menu in my website, is that an SEO problem?

Tags: seo

Let's assume that my burger-sidebar menu includes only two links; one link to my homepage and one link to my contact page.

- My homepage is already linked from the website name
- My contact page is already linked from a `position:sticky` contact us box

Allegedly I could do well without a burger-sidebar menu.

If I delete the burger-sidebar menu, is this an SEO problem? i.e. do search engines prefer websites with burger-sidebar menus ("navigation menus") over those without?

Comment: I doubt they would care. As long as the page is responsive and appropriate links are accessible there is no reason for Google to care if you use a burger sidebar menu or not.

Comment: @davidgo just a small accuracy, the menu is not `burger sidebar menu` but a menu which is opened from clicking a burger in mobile and "always sidebarish" on desktops...

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: You have to think about what is convenient for your users, not search engines.

Comment: No problem on pc. But on mobile, where there is limited viewing space, a burger menu might be a good idea. Study the behavior of your users and make them comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

No. The main consideration is to use [semantic HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics) to properly tag your navigation and contact links. The contact link you describe might be tagged as `role="complimentary"`, depending on the rest of the page structure.

Answer (score 3):

This will not be a problem for your SEO.

For future reference, if the links were **not duplicates** of others on the page, removing them would saturate your PageRank more. See the diagram below depicting how PageRank flows on a page that has 4 internal links.

[image]

Removing 2 internal links would leave you with .50 PR going to the remaining 2.

Comment: I've done tests about how Google passes PageRank.   Duplicate links don't pass extra PageRank.  Google just ignores a second duplicated link for PageRank purposes.  Regardless, I agree that it won't be an SEO problem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I don't mean pass extra, I mean saturate, or in other words _conserve_. Does your testing also confirm duplicate links don't _dilute_ the PageRank passed?

Comment: Duplicate links don't pass pagerank and don't dilute pagerank.  Googlebot just seems to ignore them 100% (at least about 10 years ago when I did the testing.)   If you put as `#fragment` onto the second URL, that would make it unique enough that Google wouldn't ignore it even though it went to the same page.

Comment: Interesting. This makes sense if you think about it...one vote per one link